# Python function returning first value twice

Tags: python, python-2.7, return-value, trigonometry

I've written this function to calculate sin(x) using Taylor series to any specified degree of accuracy, 'N terms', my problem is the results aren't being returned as expected and I can't figure out why, any help would be appreciated.

What is am expecting is: 
1  6.28318530718
2  -35.0585169332
3  46.5467323429
4  -30.1591274102
5  11.8995665347
6  -3.19507604213
7  0.624876542716
8  -0.0932457590621
9  0.0109834031461

What I am getting is:
1 None
2 6.28318530718
3 -35.0585169332
4 46.5467323429
5 -30.1591274102
6 11.8995665347
7 -3.19507604213
8 0.624876542716
9 -0.0932457590621

Thanks in advance.

```
def factorial(x):
    if x <= 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return x * factorial(x-1)

def sinNterms(x, N):
    x = float(x)

    while N >1:
        result = x
        for i in range(2, N):
            power = ((2 * i)-1)
            sign = 1
            if i % 2 == 0:
                sign = -1
            else:
                sign = 1
            result = result + (((x ** power)*sign) / factorial(power))
        return result

pi = 3.141592653589793
for i in range(1,10):
    print i, sinNterms(2*pi, i)
```

Comment: ii guess your indention is not correct for return result, you are returning result in a loop

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.

Comment: What do you mean "not as expected" You should show a sample of what is

Comment: I've added examples of what I get and what I am expecting, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you are putting the return under the for which will break it out of the while loop. You should explain if this is what you mean to do. However, given the `for i in range(1,10):` means that you will ignore the first entry and return `None` when the input argument i is 1.  Is this really what you wanted? Also, since you always exit after the calculation, you should not do a `while N > 1` but use `if N > 1` to avoid infinite recursion.

The reason why your results are off is because you are using range incorrectly. `range(2, N)` gives you a list of numbers from `2 to N-1`. Thus `range(2, 2)` gives you an empty list.

You should calculate the `range(2, N+1)`

```
def sinNterms(x, N):
    x = float(x)

    while N >1:
        result = x
        for i in range(2, N):
```

Your comment explains that you have the lines of code in the wrong order. You should have

```
def sinNterms(x, N):
    x = float(x)

    result = x
    # replace the while with an if since you do not need a loop
    # Otherwise you would get an infinite recursion
    if N > 1:
        for i in range(2, N+1):
            power = ((2 * i)-1)
            sign = 1
            if i % 2 == 0:
                sign = -1
            # The else is not needed as this is the default
            # else:
            #     sign = 1
            # use += operator for the calculation
            result += (((x ** power)*sign) / factorial(power))
    # Now return the value with the indentation under the if N > 1
    return result
```

Note that in order to handle things set factorial to return a float not an int.

An alternative method that saves some calculations is

```
def sinNterms(x, N):
    x = float(x)
    lim = 1e-12
    result = 0
    sign = 1
    # This range gives the odd numbers, saves calculation.
    for i in range(1, 2*(N+1), 2):
        # use += operator for the calculation
        temp = ((x ** i)*sign) / factorial(i)
        if fabs(temp) < lim:
            break
        result += temp
        sign *= -1
    return result
```

Comment: When the input N is 1 I should return just the value of x (6.28318530718), when N is 2 I should return the value of x - (x^3)/3! (-35.0585169332). When it is 3 I should return x - (x^3)/3! + (x^5)/5! (46.5467323429). However I return none for N = 1, as you say, and then every other value occurs at the next value of N to what should be the case.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm quite new to programming but I feel I've learned a lot from your response.

Comment: @JohnRichardson The changed code now fixes the error with None and also fixes the problem with the range.

Comment: Yes, I realised that the range should be up to N + 1 while implementing your first improvements, the function returns as expected now, thank you for being so helpful, sabbahillel.

Comment: @JohnRichardson I also fixed the range to set up the correct powers without having to calculate and started it from 1 to avoid the if.You could still use the if, but i think that this may be more readable.

Comment: @JohnRichardson Since it converges, one should allow for that case. See the change I put in